# LED + resistor in parallel with equivalent resistor, all in series with a larger resistor, LED not lighting up

Tags: led, resistors, parallel

I don't know whether I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm pretty confused. Here are a few diagrams (the ✔ or ❌ indicating the status of the LEDs when I tested it):

[image]

[image: Without 10K resistor]

[image: With LED in series with left 1K resistor]

Sorry for the lack of labels; call the 10K resistor R1, the left 1K resistor R2, and the right 1K resistor R3.

My question is: Why doesn't the LED come on in the first diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are supplying it 0.6 volts through a 2k resistor

It needs ~2v to work. you basically made a voltage divider of the two resistors (the top one and the parallel one) that divides the 6v roughly by 10 to 0.6v

Comment: Okay, so I understand why the first one doesn't work, but how come the third one does?

Comment: The third one works because it is basically the equivalent of having one diode in series with a 500ohm resistor and a 10k resistor basically the same as putting it in series with a 10.5k, half the current flows through each led and the voltages are the same across the two bottom resistors.

Answer (score 2):

One way to help simplify your question is to redraw your schematics. The rules you should consider applying are the following:

1. Arrange things on the schematic sheet so that current flows from top (more positive) to bottom (more negative.)
2. Arrange things, when signals exist, so that the signal flow goes from left (inputs) to right (outputs.)
3. Do not show wires connecting parts together if those wires also connect to a power supply rail. Simply show the connection to the power supply rail, directly. In short, do not bus power around on the schematic sheet. Excess wiring usually adds nothing to understanding a circuit, but does add "little confusing wires going from here to there" that can actually act to confuse you rather than enlighten you.

With those ideas in mind:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd09Uy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's start with the middle diagram first, because it helps make my point stronger regarding the above rules. Notice that this case now looks like two separate circuits? That's because it *is* two separate circuits. You can completely ignore \$R_2\$ in the middle diagram because now you can see that it has absolutely no bearing at all on the LED. Here, you can work out that this is a simple LED circuit with a current-limiting resistor. And it probably should work, given an LED requiring less than \$6\:\textrm{V}\$. In the case of a \$2\:\textrm{V}\$ red LED, it will probably receive \$I=\frac{6\:\textrm{V}-2\:\textrm{V}}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}\approx 4\:\text{mA}\$. And that is enough to see okay, even without a high efficiency red LED.

On the right side, you have two *equal legs*, so to speak, and both LEDs will likely receive very similar currents. But in this case, \$R_1\$ will severely limit the available current. So I'd expect rather *dim* appearances, here. Roughly speaking, and assuming \$2\:\textrm{V}\$ red LEDs as an approximation, I'd figure a total supply current (that will be divided equally for each of the two LEDs) of \$I=\frac{6\:\textrm{V}-2\:\textrm{V}}{10\:\text{k}\Omega + \left(1\:\text{k}\Omega\mid\mid 1\:\text{k}\Omega\right)}\approx 380\:\mu\text{A}\$. But split in half, this means closer to \$200\:\mu\text{A}\$ per LED. That's very dim. It also means that the LEDs probably won't occupy the entire \$2\:\textrm{V}\$ assumption, but will perhaps be a few tenths of a volt less. This will slightly increase the current, making the \$200\:\mu\text{A}\$ per LED a little more justifiable. But that's about my expectation. Dim, but probably visible. More so with the high efficiency types.

The first circuit is something else entirely. Even assuming you replaced the LED and \$R_3\$ with a dead short across \$R_2\$, the total current can't be more than \$I_{MAX}=\frac{6\:\textrm{V}}{10\:\text{k}\Omega}=600\:\mu\text{A}\$. And if you instead removed the LED and \$R_3\$ and left it open instead, the total current can't be less than \$I_{MIN}=\frac{6\:\textrm{V}}{10\:\text{k}\Omega+1\:\text{k}\Omega}\approx 364\:\mu\text{A}\$.

For a moment, let's assume \$I_{MIN}\$. In this case, the voltage drop across \$R_1\$ is \$R_1\cdot I_{MIN}\approx 3.64\:\text{V}\$. This leaves only \$6\:\text{V}-3.64\:\text{V}\approx 2.36\:\textrm{V}\$ for the two legs below \$R_1\$.

However, suppose there really was \$2.36\:\textrm{V}\$. Then \$R_2\$ would have \$\frac{2.36\:\textrm{V}}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}=2.36\:\text{mA}\$ through it! But that's not even *remotely* possible! We've already recognized that the absolute maximum possible is \$I_{MAX}=600\:\mu\text{A}\$!

So at this point a moment's reflection tells you that the voltage left over after \$R_1\$'s voltage drop is going to be a lot less than \$2.36\:\textrm{V}\$.

In fact, since we already know \$I_{MIN}\$ and \$I_{MAX}\$ from the most extreme possible circumstances imaginable, we can say for sure that the voltage must be between \$0\:\textrm{V}\$, in the case where \$D_1\$ and \$R_3\$ are treated as a dead short, and \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 364\:\mu\text{A}=364\:\text{mV}\$, in the case where \$D_1\$ and \$R_3\$ are simply removed entirely from the circuit.

So this means that there is, at *best*, less than \$364\:\text{mV}\$ across \$D_1\$ and \$R_3\$. And that is far, far too little to light up an LED. So in this case, it must obviously be off.

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding the difference between the first circuit and the third circuit is the [forward voltage drop](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/diodes/real-diode-characteristics) of the LEDs.  The forward drop depends on the LED color and on other factors.  Could be as low as 1.8V for a red LED.  Could be close to 4V for a blue one.

In a simplified model of an LED, there will be no current flow if the voltage across the LED is less than the forward voltage drop, and there will be enormous current flow (followed shortly by the LED burning out) if the voltage is any higher.

Vinzent's answer explains why your first circuit does not work:  The 10K resistor and the 1K resistor in the left leg form a [voltage divider](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/voltage-dividers) that sets the voltage seen by the LED to 0.6V.  That's less than the forward voltage for any LED, no matter what the color, so no current flows.

In your second circuit, each of the two LEDs boosts the voltage seen by the other.

Imagine: If no current flowed in either LED, then both of them would see the full 6V.  Now, let's imagine that one of the LEDs conducts:  The current effectively will be limited to a safe value by the resistors, and if there is a safe current flowing through an LED then we know that the voltage across it must be equal to its characteristic forward voltage.

But, the two LEDs both must see approximately the same voltage because they are approximately in parallel.  If they both see the characteristic forward voltage, then they both will conduct, and they both will light up.

The "approximately" is taken care of by the fact that an LED does not really have a single hard forward voltage.  There actually is a narrow range of voltages that depend on the actual current value.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers here. But for the simplest and clearest explanation would be to convert the 10k and 1k resistor divider to its Thevenin equivalent:

This circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMsOPcm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

is electrically the same as this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgW2xb.png)</sup>

So in the first circuit, you are basically trying to power your LED with a 0.545 Volt supply. Obviously, this is too low to turn on the LED.

You can find a practical explanation on the Thevenin's theorem here:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/thevenin.html

Comment: I think the 182 mV are wrong, the voltage is 545 mV. Of course 545 mV is too low to turn on the LED.

Comment: You're right, it should be 545 mV. Not sure how I got 182 mV. Will try to figure out how to edit/fix the answer.